# Apt update Hash Sum Mismatch

Tags: apt, updates

None of the other duplicate questions to this help. I've tried every single answer's suggestions. The offending issue is the xenial main source list.

```
http://ubuntu.mirror.neology.co.za/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                  
  Hash Sum mismatch
```

I've tried using every other source listed in the GUI

I've also tried

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

I even tried resetting the sources to defaults using the USA repositories instead. Result:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/3c1b1af4bfa7235f0e8ae7a098e784ed7c7d647fd23a52fc556a30e636f046e9  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/f6911df45698b03f845f8259c2eb7f39d94df9a9d6742d494a81842425314f0c  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/c609ff80c2b4fc56613d06bfabd69a9463fcf0f14ac405326542f1dc11b90a67  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/e14cb503ee4b110c672bdce0db4f4273dc65cfe8a7d82ac94395c0847a6b57fe  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Still see the exact same error, and unable to do any update whatsoever, for several months now.

I'm guessing it's because of the "shutdown" of SHA/MD5 checksums. But then the repos should be starting to roll out something else already. That issue has been going on for at least a year already. If this is the case, it is simply unacceptable!